# How can I change a css :hover state to a click event?

Tags: css

I followed the details [in the link](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/csslibrary/item/css-image-gallery/#thumb) for creating a image gallery.
And that approach works fine for me.

I want to change the mouse `hover` event to a `click` event so that when a thumbnail is clicked (instead of hover), its open image in large area.

Comment: This is entirely in css, I don't think he asking for a javascript event, try change all the 'hover' in css to 'focus', You may have to add tabindex="1" to your image elements to allow them to gain focus, I would really recommend you to consider a javascript implementation.

Comment: @jezternz, you're right, rolled back.

Answer (score 7):

Something like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/VfNdE/61/

The old hover classes become focus:

```
.thumbnail:focus{
   background-color: transparent;
   outline:none;
}

.thumbnail:focus img{
   border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

and the old html simply has tabindex added like follows for each anchor:

```
<a class="thumbnail" href="#thumb" tabindex="1">
```

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the code in your answer.

Comment: Also, remove the outline property for focused thumbnails: http://jsfiddle.net/VfNdE/2/

Comment: I saw the /2 and was too lazy to check /1. Lol.